# Eliminating theta problem from given equations and proving the identity

Tags: trigonometry

If $\cos\alpha=\cos\beta\cdot\cos\phi=\cos\gamma\cdot\cos\theta$
and $\sin\alpha=2\sin\dfrac{\phi}{2}\cdot\sin\dfrac{\theta}{2}$

then prove that
$\tan\dfrac{\alpha}{2}=\pm\tan\dfrac{\beta}{2}\cdot\tan\dfrac{\gamma}{2}$.

I could eliminate phi but theta is still haunting me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly we need to eliminate $\theta,\phi$

We have $\cos\theta=\dfrac{\cos\alpha}{\cos\lambda};\cos\phi=\dfrac{\cos\alpha}{\cos\beta}$

and $\sin^2\alpha=2\sin^2\dfrac\phi2\cdot2\sin^2\dfrac\theta2=(1-\cos\phi)(1-\cos\theta)$

$\iff1-\cos^2\alpha=\left(1-\dfrac{\cos\alpha}{\cos\beta}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{\cos\alpha}{\cos\lambda}\right)$

$$\iff\cos\beta\cos\lambda-\cos\beta\cos\lambda\cos^2\alpha$$
$$=\cos\beta\cos\lambda-(\cos\beta+\cos\lambda)\cos\alpha+\cos^2\alpha$$

Assuming $\cos\alpha\ne0,$ $$(1+\cos\beta\cos\lambda)\cos\alpha=\cos\beta+\cos\lambda$$

$$\frac{\cos\alpha}1=\frac{\cos\beta+\cos\lambda}{1+\cos\beta\cos\lambda}$$

Now apply [Componendo and dividendo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo) and use $\cos2A=\dfrac{1-\tan^2A}{1+\tan^2A}\iff\tan^2A=\dfrac{1-\cos2A}{1+\cos2A}$